# GeoJSON Layer - ArcGIS JS API - External URL with oAuth2.0

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, authentication

I am using ArcGIS JS API and connecting to an external GeoJSON service for my GeoJSON Layer. However, for security reasons oAuth2.0 has been enabled on the service.

So now I am lost as to how to connect to this service.

esri/identity/OAuthInfo has URL option only for ArcGIS Portal URL.

I believe it should be a combination of esri/identity/IdentityManager and esri/identity/Credential but it would be great if there is some step-by-step guidance.